# Какую интерполяцию выбрать для 1 миллиона точек?

Tags: математика, интерполяция

Необходимо построить ф-ию по точкам и затем ее анализировать. Точек может быть до нескольких миллионов.
Какую интерполяцию лучше выбрать с точки зрения эффективности и скорости нахождения значения функции по определенной точке в программе?
Интерполяция Лагранжа не подходит, т.к. там степень ф-ии увеличивается с увеличением кол-ва точек.
Пока рассматриваю интерполяцию, используя разложение Фурье.
Может есть еще какие-нибудь типы интерполяций, более подходящих для моей задачи?

Comment: думаю, Вам поможет укрупнение. Просто загрубите координаты, а потом удалите дубликаты.

Comment: Уточните примерный вид функции. Вы уверены, что вам нужна интерполяция, а не аппроксимация?

Comment: Нужна именно интерполяция, т.к. если мы будем искать по некоторому x, который совпадает с x из исходных данных, то значение функции должны совпадать. Поэтому и загрубить координаты не могу.

Comment: @Николай В этой теме обсуждается интерполяция, Более общую задачу следует выделить в отдельную тему.

Answer (score 6):

А зачем вам вообще использовать для интерполяции *все* точки? Воспользуйтесь какой-то из простейших - типа Ньютона - для нескольких ближайших к рассматриваемой точек - этого, думаю, будет вполне достаточно.

А вообще - желательно учитывать еще и природу имеющихся данных, это может подсказать о том, какой метод стоит использовать.

Comment: Ньютон тоже не подходит, т.к. получатся слишком сложные вычисления со степенями. Значения функции в точках, совпадающих с исходными данными, должны совпадать

Comment: Плюсую второй абзац.

Comment: Ну, если уж Ньютон сложный... Тогда линейная интерполяция или там квадратичная :)

Comment: В задаче необходимо построить несколько функций и затем решить систему уравнений.
Пример: 
По точкам получили две функции. Необходимо найти такие точки, чтобы 2 * |F2(x1) - F1(x2)| = |F1(x2) - F2(x3)|  
[изображение](http://dl3.joxi.net/drive/2018/02/02/0025/1962/1648554/54/76a0ce030c.jpg)  Поэтому функция не должна быть кусочной

Comment: Ага, типичная [XY-проблема](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/709/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-xy)... Это уже окончательное уточнение или будут еще? :)

Comment: отрезков (А, Б...) может быть сотня. И зависимости между ними могут быть самыми разными. И функций не 2е, как на картинке, а 4е. Результирующие x, должны совпадать с иксами из исходных данных.  Для всех четырех функций координаты X берутся одинаковые, а значения разные. Как-то так)

Comment: Я никак не могу понять, в чем проблема "кусочности" функций - не аналитически же вы собираетесь решать свою систему...

Comment: Пока на ум приходит аналитическое решение. Решение представляю такое (объясню на примере выше):
Необходимо составить систему уравнений. У нас всего 3 неизвестных, соответственно должно быть 3 уравнения. Одно уравнение уже есть - это 2 * |F2(x1) - F1(x2)| = |F1(x2) - F2(x3)|. Для того чтобы система была полной, нужно добавить еще 2 уравнения. Их буду итерационно подбирать. Т.е. для нашего примера, А должно быть в 2 раза меньше Б. Соответственно, в одной системе ур-ий А=1, Б=2. Далее подбираю значиния, где А=2, Б=4; А=3, Б=6 и т.д.
Если есть более оптимальный способ решения, буду рад услышать

Comment: @Николай, а если количество троек точек, удовлетворяющих вашей задаче, будет бесконечно много, то вы хотите найти их все?

Comment: @wololo, если кол-во троек точек будет бесконечно много, то буду искать такие шаблоны (А, Б), которые не пересекаются. Т.е. тройка точек одного решения не должна пересекаться с другой тройкой. Но это если решений слишком много

Answer (score 4):

Следует выбрать интерполяцию [кубическими сплайнами](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD), обеспечивающую непрерывность аппроксимирующей функции и двух её производных.

Метод отработан, литература обширна, готовые реализации найти можно.
Решение трёхдиагональной матрицы особых проблем не вызывает даже при большой размерности данных. Для повышения точности интерполяции можно уплотнить сетку на краях.

Когда не было нормальной вычислительной техники, интерполяционный сплайн получали фиксацией гибкой металлической ленты в заданных точках. Поэтому результат устроит однозначно.
Интерполяция по методу Фурье приведёт к паразитным осцилляциям, так что не может быть рекомендована.

---

ИНТЕРПОЛЯЦИЯ КУБИЧЕСКИМИ СПЛАЙНАМИ

Пусть заданы абсциссы точек кривой 
x<sub>0</sub> < x<sub>1</sub> < … < x<sub>n</sub>
и соответствующие им ординаты 
y<sub>0</sub>, y<sub>1</sub>, … , y<sub>n</sub>.
Естественный кубический сплайн - это кусочно-полиномиальная функция
**S<sub>i</sub>(x) = a<sub>i</sub> + b<sub>i</sub>(x-x<sub>i</sub>) + <sup>1</sup>/<sub>2</sub>c<sub>i</sub>(x-x<sub>i</sub>)<sup>2</sup> + <sup>1</sup>/<sub>6</sub>d<sub>i</sub>(x-x<sub>i</sub>)<sup>3</sup>,  x ∈ [x<sub>i</sub>, x<sub>i+1</sub>],  i = 0, …, n-1,   (1)**
для которой:
S<sub>i</sub>(x<sub>i</sub>) = y<sub>i</sub>, S<sub>i</sub>(x<sub>i+1</sub>) =
y<sub>i+1</sub>, i = 0, …, n-1, 
(условия интерполяции),
S'<sub>i</sub>(x<sub>i+1</sub>) = S'<sub>i+1</sub>(x<sub>i+1</sub>), S''<sub>i</sub>(x<sub>i+1</sub>) = S''<sub>i+1</sub>(x<sub>i+1</sub>), i = 0, …, n-2, 
(условия непрерывности производных),
S<sub>0</sub>''(x<sub>0</sub>) = S<sub>n-1</sub>''(x<sub>n</sub>) = 0 
(граничные условия для естественного сплайна).
Это приводит к системе уравнений на коэффициенты сплайна вида

a<sub>i</sub> = y<sub>i</sub>,  a<sub>i</sub> + b<sub>i</sub>h<sub>i</sub> + <sup>1</sup>/<sub>2</sub>c<sub>i</sub>h<sub>i</sub><sup>2</sup> + <sup>1</sup>/<sub>6</sub>d<sub>i</sub>h<sub>i</sub><sup>3</sup> = y<sub>i+1</sub>  при i = 0, …, n-1,
b<sub>i</sub> + c<sub>i</sub>h<sub>i</sub> + <sup>1</sup>/<sub>2</sub>c<sub>i</sub>h<sub>i</sub><sup>2</sup> = b<sub>i+1</sub>,  c<sub>i</sub> + d<sub>i</sub>h<sub>i</sub> = c<sub>i+1</sub>  при i = 0, …, n-2,
c<sub>0</sub> = 0,   c<sub>n-1</sub> + d<sub>n-1</sub>h<sub>n-1</sub> = 0,

где h<sub>i</sub> = x<sub>i+1</sub> - x<sub>i</sub>  при i = 0, …, n-1.

Поскольку
**a<sub>i</sub> = y<sub>i</sub>,  d<sub>i</sub> = (c<sub>i+1</sub> -
 c<sub>i</sub>) / h<sub>i</sub>  при i = 0, …, n-1,  c<sub>n</sub> = 0,   (2)**

то система на оставшиеся коэффициенты принимает вид:

**h<sub>i</sub>b<sub>i</sub> = y<sub>i+1</sub> - y<sub>i</sub> -
 <sup>1</sup>/<sub>6</sub>(c<sub>i+1</sub> + 2c<sub>i</sub>)h<sub>i</sub><sup>2</sup>,   (3)**
h<sub>i</sub>(c<sub>i+1</sub>+c<sub>i</sub>) = 2(b<sub>i+1</sub>-b<sub>i</sub>),
где  i = 0, …, n-2, c<sub>0</sub> = 0 .

Уравнение (3) в явном виде содержит **b<sub>i</sub>**.
Умножая второе уравнение системы на **3h<sub>i</sub>h<sub>i+1</sub>** и используя (3), приходим к СЛАУ с трёхдиагональной матрицей для **c<sub>i</sub>**:

3h<sub>i</sub><sup>2</sup>h<sub>i+1</sub>(c<sub>i+1</sub> + c<sub>i</sub>) = 6h<sub>i</sub>(y<sub>i+2</sub> - y<sub>i+1</sub>) - h<sub>i</sub>h<sub>i+1</sub><sup>2</sup>(c<sub>i+2</sub>+2c<sub>i+1</sub>)
-6h<sub>i+1</sub>(y<sub>i+1</sub> - y<sub>i</sub>) + h<sub>i</sub><sup>2</sup>h<sub>i+1</sub>(c<sub>i+1</sub> + 2c<sub>i</sub>),
или
h<sub>i</sub>h<sub>i+1</sub>(h<sub>i+1</sub>c<sub>i+2</sub> + 2(h<sub>i</sub>+h<sub>i+1</sub>)c<sub>i+1</sub>+h<sub>i</sub>c<sub>i</sub>) = 6(h<sub>i</sub>y<sub>i+2</sub> - (h<sub>i</sub>+h<sub>i+1</sub>)y<sub>i+1</sub> 
+h<sub>i+1</sub>y<sub>i</sub>),
где i = 0...n-1, причём c<sub>0</sub> = c<sub>n</sub> = 0.

Полученную систему можно записать в виде

**c<sub>i+1</sub> = r<sub>i</sub> - (p<sub>i</sub>c<sub>i</sub> + q<sub>i</sub>c<sub>i+2</sub>),  (4)**
где
**p<sub>i</sub> = <sup>1</sup>/<sub>2</sub>h<sub>i</sub> / (h<sub>i</sub> + h<sub>i+1</sub>), 

q<sub>i</sub> = <sup>1</sup>/<sub>2</sub>h<sub>i+1</sub> / (h<sub>i</sub> + h<sub>i+1</sub>), 

r<sub>i</sub> = 3(h<sub>i</sub>y<sub>i+2</sub> - (h<sub>i</sub> + h<sub>i+1</sub>)y<sub>i+1</sub> + h<sub>i+1</sub>y<sub>i</sub>) / (h<sub>i</sub>h<sub>i+1</sub>(h<sub>i</sub> + h<sub>i+1</sub>)).   (5)**

Диагональные коэффициенты матрицы превосходят по модулю сумму остальных элементов той же строки. Это говорит о том, что вместо стандартного метода прогонки может быть использован итерационный метод Зейделя, при котором коэффициенты **c<sub>i</sub>** изначально задаются нулями, а потом к ним применяют формулы (4) до тех пор, пока максимум относительного отклонения не опустится ниже требуемого порога.

Таким образом, формулы (2)-(5) позволяют вычислить все коэффициенты сплайна (1).

---

ПРОГРАММА

```
    public static void AddFactorVector(double[] vec, double factor, double[] v)
    {
        vec[0] += factor * v[0];
        vec[1] += factor * v[1];
    }

    public static double[][] CSpline(double[] x, double[] y, bool freeze)
    {
        int i, msize = x.Length - 1;
        double w, u6 = 1D / 6, d0, d, eps = 1e-13D;
        double[] h = new double[msize], u = new double[msize],
            p = new double[msize - 1], q = new double[msize - 1],
            r = new double[msize - 1], uu = new double[msize - 1], 
            c = new double[msize + 1];
        double[][] v = new double[msize + 1][], result = new double[msize][];

        for (i = 0; i < msize; i++)
            h[i] = x[i + 1] - x[i];
        for (i = 0; i < msize - 1; i++)
        {
            w = 0.5D /(h[i] + h[i + 1]);
            p[i] = h[i] *  w;
            q[i] = h[i + 1] * w;
            r[i] = 3D * (h[i] * y[i + 2] - (h[i] + h[i + 1]) * y[i + 1] + h[i + 1] * y[i]) 
                / (h[i] * h[i+1] * (h[i] + h[i+1]));
        }
        if (freeze)
        {   // условия замораживания коэффициента d на краях
            w = h[1] + h[1];
            p[0] = 0;
            q[0] = (h[1] - h[0]) / (w + h[0]);
            r[0] *= w / (w + h[0]);
            w = h[msize - 2] + h[msize - 2];
            p[msize - 2] = (h[msize - 2] - h[msize - 1]) / (w + h[msize -1]);
            q[msize - 2] = 0;
            r[msize - 2] *= w / (w + h[msize - 1]);
        }
        d0 = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < msize + 1; i++)
            c[i] = 0;
        for (i = 1; i < msize - 1; i++)
            d0 = Math.Max(d0, Math.Abs(r[i]));
        d = d0;
        //return result;
        while (d > d0 * eps)
        {
            for (i = 1; i < msize; i++)
                c[i] = r[i - 1] - p[i - 1] * c[i - 1] - q[i - 1] * c[i + 1];
            d = 0;
            for (i = 1; i < msize; i++)
                d = Math.Max(d, Math.Abs(r[i - 1] - c[i] - p[i - 1] * c[i - 1] - q[i - 1] * c[i + 1]));
        }
        Console.Write("\nd0 = {0}  d = {1}", d0, d);
        for (i = 0; i < msize; i++)
            result[i] = new double[] {
                x[i],
                y[i],
                (y[i+1] - y[i])/h[i] - u6 * h[i] * (c[i + 1] + c[i] + c[i]),
                0.5D * c[i],
                (c[i + 1] - c[i]) / (6D * h[i]) };

        return result;
    }

    public static double VSpline(double[][] s, double x) {
        int slen = s.Length, ind = slen - 1, dind = ind, newind;
        double dx;
        double[] cs;

        if (x < s[ind][0])
            while ((dind /= 2) > 0)
                if (x < s[newind = (ind - dind)][0])
                    ind = newind;
        cs = s[ind];
        dx = x - cs[0];
        //Console.WriteLine("\nx = {0:F3} ind = {1}  s[ind][0] = {2}", x, ind, cs[0]);

        return ((cs[4] * dx + cs[3]) * dx + cs[2]) * dx + cs[1];
    }

    public static void T(string text, Stopwatch timer)
    {
        TimeSpan ts = timer.Elapsed;
        string elapsedTime = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}.{3:00}",
            ts.Hours, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds, ts.Milliseconds / 10);
        Console.Write(text + elapsedTime);
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        bool freeze = false;
        int i, n = 20;
        double min_dx = 0.03D, max_dx = 0.05D, vx, stepx, a = min_dx * n/4, b = a + a, c = b + a , dy;
        double[] x = new double[n + 1], y = new double[n + 1], z = new double[n+1];
        double[][] s;
        Random rand = new Random();
        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();

        x[0] = 0;
        y[0] = 0;
        for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            x[i] = x[i - 1] + min_dx + rand.NextDouble() * (max_dx - min_dx);
            y[i] = Math.Sin(x[i]);
            z[i] = (x[i] - a) * (x[i] - b) * (x[i] - c);
        }
        Console.Write("\nРасчёт сплайна для кубического полинома:");
        sw.Start();
        s = CSpline(x, z, freeze);
        sw.Stop();
        T("\nRuntime = ", sw);
        Console.WriteLine();
        stepx = (x[n] - x[0]) / n;
        dy = 0;
        for (i = 0, vx = x[0]; i <= n; i++, vx += stepx)
        {
            dy = Math.Max(dy, Math.Abs(VSpline(s, vx) - (vx - a) * (vx - b) * (vx - c)));
            if (i < 20)
                Console.WriteLine("x = {0:F3}  P3(x) = {1:F3}  VSpline(x) = {2:F3}  delta = {3:F6}",
                vx, (vx - a) * (vx - b) * (vx - c), VSpline(s, vx),
                VSpline(s, vx) - (vx - a) * (vx - b) * (vx - c));
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Максимальное отклонение: " + dy);
        Console.Write("\nРасчёт сплайна для синусоиды:");
        sw.Reset();
        sw.Start();
        s = CSpline(x, y, freeze);
        sw.Stop();
        T("\nRuntime = ", sw);
        Console.WriteLine();
        stepx = (x[n] - x[0]) / n;
        dy = 0;
        for (i = 0, vx = x[0]; i <= n; i++, vx += stepx)
        {
            dy = Math.Max(dy, Math.Abs(VSpline(s, vx) - Math.Sin(vx)));
            if(i < 20)
            Console.WriteLine("x = {0:F3}  sin x = {1:F3}  VSpline(x) = {2:F3}  delta = {3:F6}",
                vx, Math.Sin(vx), VSpline(s, vx), VSpline(s, vx) - Math.Sin(vx));
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Максимальное отклонение: " + dy);
    }
```

---

РЕЗУЛЬТАТЫ

```
Расчёт сплайна для кубического полинома:
d0 = 4,06461608055262  d = 1,45369827286856E-13
Runtime = 00:00:00.01
x = 0,000  P3(x) = -0,020  VSpline(x) = 0,003  delta = 0,023591
x = 0,042  P3(x) = -0,011  VSpline(x) = -0,004  delta = 0,007719
x = 0,084  P3(x) = -0,005  VSpline(x) = -0,004  delta = 0,001165
x = 0,126  P3(x) = -0,001  VSpline(x) = -0,002  delta = -0,000173
x = 0,168  P3(x) = 0,001  VSpline(x) = 0,001  delta = 0,000080
x = 0,210  P3(x) = 0,001  VSpline(x) = 0,001  delta = -0,000016
x = 0,252  P3(x) = 0,001  VSpline(x) = 0,001  delta = 0,000005
x = 0,294  P3(x) = 0,000  VSpline(x) = 0,000  delta = -0,000002
x = 0,336  P3(x) = -0,001  VSpline(x) = -0,001  delta = 0,000000
x = 0,378  P3(x) = -0,001  VSpline(x) = -0,001  delta = 0,000000
x = 0,420  P3(x) = -0,001  VSpline(x) = -0,001  delta = 0,000000
x = 0,462  P3(x) = 0,001  VSpline(x) = 0,001  delta = 0,000000
x = 0,504  P3(x) = 0,004  VSpline(x) = 0,004  delta = 0,000000
x = 0,546  P3(x) = 0,009  VSpline(x) = 0,009  delta = 0,000000
x = 0,588  P3(x) = 0,017  VSpline(x) = 0,017  delta = 0,000000
x = 0,630  P3(x) = 0,028  VSpline(x) = 0,028  delta = 0,000000
x = 0,672  P3(x) = 0,043  VSpline(x) = 0,043  delta = 0,000000
x = 0,714  P3(x) = 0,061  VSpline(x) = 0,061  delta = 0,000000
x = 0,756  P3(x) = 0,084  VSpline(x) = 0,084  delta = -0,000397
x = 0,798  P3(x) = 0,112  VSpline(x) = 0,112  delta = 0,000147
Максимальное отклонение: 0,0235914346488723

Расчёт сплайна для синусоиды:
d0 = 1,02409552275377  d = 3,53640727812632E-14
Runtime = 00:00:00.00
x = 0,000  sin x = 0,000  VSpline(x) = 0,000  delta = -0,000001
x = 0,042  sin x = 0,042  VSpline(x) = 0,042  delta = 0,000000
x = 0,084  sin x = 0,084  VSpline(x) = 0,084  delta = 0,000000
x = 0,126  sin x = 0,126  VSpline(x) = 0,126  delta = 0,000000
x = 0,168  sin x = 0,167  VSpline(x) = 0,167  delta = 0,000000
x = 0,210  sin x = 0,208  VSpline(x) = 0,208  delta = 0,000000
x = 0,252  sin x = 0,249  VSpline(x) = 0,249  delta = 0,000000
x = 0,294  sin x = 0,290  VSpline(x) = 0,290  delta = 0,000000
x = 0,336  sin x = 0,330  VSpline(x) = 0,330  delta = 0,000000
x = 0,378  sin x = 0,369  VSpline(x) = 0,369  delta = 0,000000
x = 0,420  sin x = 0,408  VSpline(x) = 0,408  delta = -0,000002
x = 0,462  sin x = 0,446  VSpline(x) = 0,446  delta = 0,000000
x = 0,504  sin x = 0,483  VSpline(x) = 0,483  delta = 0,000000
x = 0,546  sin x = 0,519  VSpline(x) = 0,519  delta = 0,000000
x = 0,588  sin x = 0,554  VSpline(x) = 0,554  delta = 0,000000
x = 0,630  sin x = 0,589  VSpline(x) = 0,589  delta = 0,000000
x = 0,672  sin x = 0,622  VSpline(x) = 0,622  delta = 0,000000
x = 0,714  sin x = 0,655  VSpline(x) = 0,655  delta = 0,000000
x = 0,756  sin x = 0,686  VSpline(x) = 0,686  delta = 0,000091
x = 0,798  sin x = 0,716  VSpline(x) = 0,716  delta = -0,000034
Максимальное отклонение: 9,14491789769656E-05
```